# DIV should fill available space

Tags: css, html

I have this [**code**](http://jsfiddle.net/cD2RK/)

```
<!-- <body> (automatically added by jsFiddle) -->
<header id="header">
    <h1>Title</h1>
</header>

<div id="mainContent">
    Some text. End.<br />
</div>
<!-- </body> -->
```

How can I stretch `#mainContent` to fill all the available space below `#header` ?

That's for a **Windows 8** app, so **I can use CSS 3 (including *-ms-grid-**) and JavaScript** without worrying about browser support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **display:table** property for this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <header id="header">
     <h1>Title</h1>
    </header>

    <div id="mainContent">
      Some text. End.<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body,html{
    height:100%;
}
.parent{
    display:table;
    height:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:100%
}
#header, #mainContent {
    background:red;
    display:table-row;
}

/* How can I make #header to fill the full available left space */
#header {
    height:10%;
    background:green;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/cD2RK/3/

Comment: Thanks, it looks good. I'll test it when my reinstallation of Visual Studio is finally completed ;)